# How to compare positions of two elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have been trying to make this work since the beginning of this week but couldn't figure it out. I have two elements in my HTML file. They are on the same vertical lane, element1 is moving 60ems to the left horizontally with each button click. I have to compare the positions of these two elements and detect whether element1 has passed the element2 with an if/else statement. When it passes I want to move the element1 to its initial position and start over. But if statement never shoots, it always jumps to else statement.

I have tried comparing following properties:

```
$('#elemet1').position();
$('#elemet1').position().left;
$('#elemet1').offset();
$('#elemet1').offsetLeft;
$('#elemet1').css("position");
$('#elemet1').css("left");
$('#elemet1').css("margin");
$('#elemet1').left;
```

I tried to compare the positions like below:

```
$(function () {
      $("button").click(function () {
          var position1 = $('#element1').css("left");
          var position2 = $('#element2').css("left");
          if (position1 <= position2) {
              $("#element1").animate({left:'+=240em'}, 600);
          }
          else {
              $("#element1").animate({left:'-=60em'}, 600);
          }
      });
  });
```

If you can give me an answer or direct me to another post I will appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: The style I use is below:

```
.element2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 60em;
    height: 40em;
    bottom: 8em;
    background: rgba(242, 210, 139, 0.6);
    border-radius: 1.2em;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;

#element1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 180em;
    width: 60em;
    height: 40em;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And I should have mentioned this at the beginning: element1 is inside element2:

```
 <div class="element2">
      <img id="element1" src="image/bg1.png" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Dump out the values of position1/position2 with an alert or console.log. Possibly you're getting a string value, something like '10px', rather than an int. if so, you'll need to parseInt() those values before doing the comparison.

Comment: I have tried to parse them but no luck :/

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the current position of an element:

```
$('#element').position().left;
```

If you need position relative to the document (instead of relative to a parent element) you can use:

```
$('#element').offset().left;
```

You should just be able to compare the return values of these for the different elements directly. Here's some sample code that works for me, note there is no need to parse since they always return pixel values.

```
  var pos = Math.max($(w).scrollTop(), 38),
      top = $(ballon).position().top,
      dist = Math.abs(pos-top),
      time = dist > 1000 ? 2000 : dist / 0.15;

  if (pos + $(w).height() >= pHeight) {
    pos = pHeight - bHeight - gHeight;
    $(ballon).animate({'top': pos}, time, 'easeInOutSine');
  }
  else if (dist > 150 || pos < 100) {
    $(ballon).animate({'top': pos}, time, 'easeInOutBack');
  }
```

Comment: I have tried these too, I cannot use .position().top because they are at the same y position all the time. .position().left didn't help, it still jumps to else statement

Comment: Try .offset().left. If neither of those work, then there is something else wrong with your code. An element can't be changing position without one of those indicating the change. You'll need to open up your debugger to see what's going on (or create a jsfiddle showing the problem and we can help).

Comment: When I use .offset().left button doesn't even work, element1 doesn't move at all. I will check my code in more detail. Thank you.